# How to avoid "this" as Class parameter

Tags: java, constructor

I dont think its pretty to use `this` as a class parameter because there could occur errors if the order of initialization of the objects is not right.

Whats best practise to avoid this?

Example:

```
public class Game{

    private Player p1, p2, currentPlayer;
    private Board board;

    Game() {
        board = new Board(this);
    }

    private boolean hasFieldsToBeClicked() {
            return board.checkFieldsToBeClicked();
        }
```

Comment: It's very common to pass `this` as a parameter to another constructor. I would not assume that it is a problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's hard to give any concrete recommendations when we don't know the details of what you're trying to achieve. Why does the `Board` need to know about the `Game`, for example? If you can avoid the cyclic dependency, you're more likely to be able to avoid passing `this`.

Comment: @khelwood this *is* a problem, it's unsafe publication (i.e. you are leaking the reference to the `Game` before it has finished being initialized).

Comment: @AndyTurner I see what you mean. I guess it depends on what you're doing with `this` when you get it. I assumed it was just so that `Board` could store a reference to the `Game` object for later.

Comment: @DaisyShipton The Game class contains basically all the logic of the game. The `Board` class is basically the GUI. `Gam`e needs to be able to call methods from `Borad`.
Maybe there is fundeamentally something wrong with that?

Comment: That doesn't explain why `Board` needs a reference to `Game` - it explains the reverse. (I'm not sure what you mean by the `Board` class being "the guy".) But basically it's worth considering whether you can refactor to avoid that dependency. If the board is just the data of what pieces are where, etc, why would it need to call into `Game`?

Comment: If you absolutely need the reference during construction, then you could consider making Board an inner class of Game. Then it gets a reference by default. Or you could consider adding a setter method, and set the Board/Game relationship after the constructor is complete.

Comment: @DaisyShipton For example the `Game` class contains the current player. If the `Board` needs to display this, it has to be able to call ` dame.getCurrentPlayer()`

Comment: @matt If `Board` is an inner class of `Game`, that inherently has all the same possible pitfalls of passing `this` to `Board`'s constructor.

Comment: @khelwood It isn't quit the same semantically because it is in the same class.

Comment: @FabianZbinden: Perhaps it would be better for `Board.display()` to accept a `Game` parameter then? Or make the `Game` responsible for displaying the players? But it's *really* hard to discuss this with only bits and pieces of information. My advice is to try to redesign to avoid the cyclic dependency - but that's about all I can say without more concrete information.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I just need to know the possible options, I have not heard of before. So I note to myself:
1. Passing object as METHOD parameter instead of class parameter.
2. Create a setRelationship() Method outside of the constructor to avoid beeing it in the class constructor.

Is this about the right way to go?

Comment: @FabianZbinden: Again, we can't know the "right" way to go without knowing more context. If you try to make your classes immutable, you can't have a `setRelationship` method, for example. (And even if they're mutable, you'd end up with a partially-initialized object until you called `setRelationship`. Is that a problem? It might be, or it might not be.)

Answer (score 6):

From a design point of view: just don't do it here!

Meaning: a `Board` represents a *board*. Does your chess board know about the game you are currently having, or not?

In other words: passing `this` can be ok, but as you pointed out, it can also be a problem. Thus the best practice is: only pass `this` if you have good reasons to. Especially when it occurs within the constructor and `this` is still in the process of being initialized.

Enabling a chess board to know about an ongoing game isn't really a good reason.

Keep in mind: your classes/objects should *model* the real world. Only establish relations that are meaningful!

So the real answer here would be to look into *why* your Board class needs to know about the Game class, to then get rid of that dependency.

Comment: So let's say I want to get rid of the dependency. How do I realize `Board` being the GUI of something that happens in another class. I see no reason to keep track of a players score in the GUI class which in my case is `Board`, On the other hand I dont see much sense in initializing a label and filing it with the score as ouptut in the `Game` class.

How do I get to know about the score if I should get rid of the dependency?

(All this is just an example and a bit more complex)

Comment: @FabianZbinden: Perhaps `Board` shouldn't be the GUI then. Perhaps it should just be the data model for the board itself. Then create a separate GUI class which knows about both the `Game` and the `Board`, but which neither of *those* need to know about. Separation of concerns can solve a lot of these problems.

Comment: @FabianZbinden Exactly as Daisy is saying: merging the "business" logic of your board with any kind of UI representation is already a step in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

1) What about a builder, which creates the game and the board at first without the other. Then the builder can set the Board in the Game and the Game in the Board.

2) It seems the Board is an inherent part of the Game.

- a) So you could use interfaces for Game and Board and implement both in one class.
- b) If you want to separate the Game from the Board you could use an inner class for the Board within the Game.